# Mysql date difference?

Tags: mysql, sql

task is to get date difference and here's my sql statement:

```
select start_date, end_date, a_name
           from b
           WHERE DateDiff(start_date, end_date) AS DF >= 1000 AND
           department_name = 'abc';
```

And I keep getting errors. I am new to SQL so kinda lost now.

Comment: Please always include the exact error message, table structure and other necessary details in the question

Comment: Remove "AS DF" which was for a column title DF. Then search for datediff MySQL.

Comment: reverse dates in `datediff(end_date,start_date)`

Answer (score 0):

`as` provides an alias (a name) for a result column or joined table or subquery; it doesn't belong in the middle of an expression.

Comment: Thanks! TT but then how can I compare the datediff value? no idea at all..

Comment: @were: by removing `AS DF` obviously. (And then you may want to switch `start_date` and `end_date` in order to get a positive result rather than a negative one. Read the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your query. The first one is the syntax error. Alias names are given in the `SELECT` clause, not in the `WHERE` clause. What would that alias name be for, anyway? Remove `AS DF`.

Then, there is a semantical error. You are comparing the two dates with `DATEDIFF` and thus get the difference in days. `DATEDIFF` subtracts the second date from the first one. Accordingly, you subtract the `end_date` from the `start_date`, which will result in a negative number. See here how `DATEDIFF` works in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

Here is the corrected query:

```
select start_date, end_date, a_name
from b
where datediff(end_date, start_date) >= 1000 
and department_name = 'abc'
order by start_date;
```

When not sure which way `DATEDIFF` works and to avoid this doubt with any future reader, you can also use `ABS` here:

```
where abs(datediff(end_date, start_date)) >= 1000
```

Thus the order of the two parameters doesn't matter any more and everybody sees at first glance that this must work.